# Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, related to Grassmannian

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannian

This question arose when I was trying to understand a proof related to the Grassmannian of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $P=\langle e_1,\ldots,e_k\rangle$ and $Q=\langle e_{k+1},\ldots,e_n\rangle$, where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $P\oplus Q=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define projections $\pi_P:\mathbb{R}^n\to P$, $\pi_Q:\mathbb{R}^n\to Q$.

Suppose $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace which intersects $Q$ trivially.

I know that $\pi_P|_S$ is an isomorphism.

Why is it true that there are $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in Q$ such that $e_i+a_i\in S$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ ?

Comment: The key observation is that $S$ is complementary to $Q$, so any element of $\Bbb R^n$ (in particular, $e_1, \ldots, e_k$) can be written as a sum of an element of $Q$ and an element of $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** The key observation is that $S$ is a complement of $Q$ in $\Bbb R^n$, so that any vector in $\Bbb R^n$ (in particular, the basis vectors $e_1, \ldots e_k$) can be written as a sum of a vector in $Q$ and vector in $S$.

Answer (score 2):

To help develop intuition,  take a small example:   the $x$-axis, $y$-axis for $P,Q$, and $S=\{t(1,1):t\in\Bbb R\}$.  Then $e_1+e_2=(1,1)$.

Further,  let $S_\theta=\{t(\cos\theta, \sin\theta):t\in \Bbb R$.  Then any $\theta \ne\pi/2$ works.   Then $e_1+\tan\theta\cdot e_2\in S_\theta$.

So this appears true.

Since $P\oplus Q=\Bbb R^n$, there have to be such $a_i$.  If $S=P$, they can all be zero.

I guess I have done the base case for a proof by induction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The intuition is helpful but doing it by induction would be very complicated, I think, since it must be shown both for all $n$ and for all dimensions $k<n$ of the subspace $S$.

Comment: I agree,  was it stated as if obvious?   Apparently an induction would go through though.   Since $\Bbb R^n=\Bbb R^{n-1}\oplus\Bbb R$, and the induction hypothesis would hold on both $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ and $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f = \pi_P\mid_S$ is isomrophism let $a_i = f^{-1}\left(e_i\right) - e_i$. So $\pi_P\left(a_i\right)=0$ this proves that $a_i \in Q$. Your claim follows immediately.